# How should I reuse Bottle router code between projects?

Tags: python, bottle

Normally I reuse code in Python by encapsulating it into a class.

But with Bottle I basically write functions at the global level decorated with the route.

Eg.

```
@get("/foo/<id>")
def foo(id) :
   return f(id)
```

I now have two projects that share maybe 80% of their routed handlers like this.

How can I best make the commonalities reusable between them?

I don't think I can decorate methods of a class because of the explicit self. So is there another way to share code between two different projects except copy and paste?

Comment: Are you hoping to reuse the routing (decorator), or the implementation (body of foo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hoping to reuse your implementations (function `foo` in your example), then something like this might work for you:

```
from bottle import Bottle
from path.to.my.common.lib import foo

app = Bottle()

app.get("/foo/<id>")(foo)

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

All I'm doing there is using the decorator explicitly, rather than with its nice `@` syntax.

Comment: That sounds plausible. I'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also merge routes.

```
from myclient import clientRoute
from myapi import apiRoute
from mysandbox import sandboxRoute
app = bottle.app()
for nftyRoute in (myclient , myapi , mysandbox):
    app.merge(nftyRoute)
```

and in each of the route files you would have simply: (Ex. myclient.py)

```
from bottle import Bottle, get, post, request, response, template, redirect, abort
clientRoute = Bottle()
```